# No consigo seleccionar una carta

Tags: javascript, html, css

Este es mi código, es un juego de cartas y no se porque no me selecciona una carta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">`
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>

        html {
            background: url("kungfupanda.jpg");
        }

        .contenedor-jugador {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .carta {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            width: calc(20% - 20px);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        }

        .seleccionada {
            border: 5px solid limegreen;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #boton {
            margin-left: 850px;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #contenedor-jugador1,
        #contenedor-jugador2 {
            margin-top: 25px;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 150px;
            max-height: 150px;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Juego de cartas</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Juego de Kung Fu Panda</h1>
    <button onclick="iniciarCombate()" id="boton">Iniciar Combate</button>
    <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Borrar</button>
    <h1>Jugador 1</h1>
    <div id="contenedor-jugador1"></div>
    <h1>Jugador 2</h1>
    <div id="contenedor-jugador2"></div>

    <template id="cartaTemplate">
        <article id="" class="carta">
            <img src="">
            <h3>Nombre</h3>
            <p>Ataque: <span class="ataque"></span></p>
            <p>Defensa: <span class="defensa"></span></p>
            <p>Velocidad: <span class="velocidad"></span></p>
            <p>Vida: <span class="vida"></span></p>
        </article>
    </template>

    <script>

        let cartaJugador1 = null;
        let cartaJugador2 = null;

        function iniciarCombate() {
            if (!cartaJugador1 || !cartaJugador2) {
                alert("Selecciona una carta para cada jugador antes de iniciar el combate.");
                return;
            }

            combatir(cartaJugador1, cartaJugador2);

            // Reiniciar las variables para la próxima ronda
            cartaJugador1 = null;
            cartaJugador2 = null;
        }

        function combatir(cartaJugador1, cartaJugador2) {
            let atacante = null;
            let defensor = null;

            if (parseInt(cartaJugador1.data.velocidad) > parseInt(cartaJugador2.data.velocidad)) {

                atacante = cartaJugador1;
                defensor = cartaJugador2;
            } else {
                atacante = cartaJugador2;
                defensor = cartaJugador1;
            }

            combatirRonda(atacante, defensor);

            while (parseInt(cartaJugador1.data.salud) > 0 && parseInt(cartaJugador2.data.salud) > 0) {
                [atacante, defensor] = [defensor, atacante];
                combatirRonda(atacante, defensor);
            }

            if (parseInt(cartaJugador1.data.salud) <= 0) {
                alert("¡Jugador 2 gana!");
            } else {
                alert("¡Jugador 1 gana!");
            }
        }

        function combatirRonda(atacante, defensor) {
            const ataque = parseInt(atacante.data.ataque);
            const defensa = parseInt(defensor.data.defensa);
            let danio = 0;

            if (ataque > defensa) {
                danio = ataque - defensa;
            } else {
                danio = 10;
            }

            const vidaActual = parseInt(defensor.data.salut);

            const nuevaVida = Math.max(0, vidaActual - danio);

            defensor.data.salud = nuevaVida;
            defensor.querySelector("p:last-child").textContent = `Vida: ${nuevaVida}`;
            defensor.classList.add("seleccionada");
        }

        function crearCarta(data, jugador) {
            const template = document.getElementById("cartaTemplate");
            const nuevaCarta = template.content.cloneNode(true);

            // Configura los datos de la carta usando data
            nuevaCarta.querySelector("img").src = data.imatge;
            nuevaCarta.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = data.nom;
            nuevaCarta.querySelector(".ataque").innerHTML = data.atac;
            nuevaCarta.querySelector(".defensa").innerHTML = data.defensa;
            nuevaCarta.querySelector(".velocidad").innerHTML = data.velocitat;
            nuevaCarta.querySelector(".vida").innerHTML = data.salut;

            nuevaCarta.addEventListener("click", () => seleccionarCarta(nuevaCarta, jugador));


            return nuevaCarta;
        }

        function seleccionarCarta(carta, jugador) {
            // Verifica si ya hay una carta seleccionada para el jugador
            if (jugador === 1) {
                if (cartaJugador1) {
                    cartaJugador1.classList.remove("seleccionada");
                }
                cartaJugador1 = carta;
            } else {
                if (cartaJugador2) {
                    cartaJugador2.classList.remove("seleccionada");
                }
                cartaJugador2 = carta;
            }

            // Asegura que la carta seleccionada tenga la clase
            carta.classList.toggle("seleccionada");
        }

        const contenedorJugador1 = document.getElementById("contenedor-jugador1");
        const contenedorJugador2 = document.getElementById("contenedor-jugador2");

        let cartas;

        fetch("info.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                cartas = data;
                const cartasShuffle = cartas.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    const jugador1Carta = crearCarta(cartasShuffle[i], 1);
                    const jugador2Carta = crearCarta(cartasShuffle[i + 5], 2);

                    contenedorJugador1.appendChild(jugador1Carta);
                    contenedorJugador2.appendChild(jugador2Carta);
                }
            });
    </script>

</body>

</html>.
```

Y este el Json:

```
[
    { "nom": "Po", "atac": 100, "defensa": 85, "velocitat": 60, "salut": 120, "imatge": "po.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Tigresa", "atac": 95, "defensa": 80, "velocitat": 65, "salut": 120, "imatge": "tigresa.png" },
    { "nom": "Mono", "atac": 90, "defensa": 75, "velocitat": 70, "salut": 120, "imatge": "mono.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Grulla", "atac": 92, "defensa": 78, "velocitat": 68, "salut": 110, "imatge": "grulla.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Tai Lung", "atac": 94, "defensa": 82, "velocitat": 75, "salut": 130, "imatge": "tailung.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Shifu", "atac": 93, "defensa": 88, "velocitat": 72, "salut": 115, "imatge": "shifu.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Víbora", "atac": 40, "defensa": 30, "velocitat": 100, "salut": 190, "imatge": "vibora.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Maestro Oogway", "atac": 88, "defensa": 82, "velocitat": 60, "salut": 110, "imatge": "oogway.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Mantis", "atac": 90, "defensa": 80, "velocitat": 70, "salut": 100, "imatge": "mantis.jpg" },
    { "nom": "Maestro Rino", "atac": 96, "defensa": 85, "velocitat": 68, "salut": 140, "imatge": "rino.jpg" }
]
```

He preguntado por diferentes foros, ia y no consigo que me resuelvan este error*

Comment: Dado que es HTML / CSS / JS, podés hacer que tu código sea ejecutable en la pregunta misma, a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Como dice @padaleiana podrías crear un snippet para mostrar tu código y que se pueda ejecutar. Esto facilita a las personas que te quieran ayudar, ya que no tendrían que reproducir el código en local.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la etiqueta `<template>` y la forma en la que accedes a su contenido.

Cuando dentro de `crearCarta(...)` haces:

```js
const nuevaCarta = template.content.cloneNode(true);
```

Obtienes un objeto del tipo [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) (podrás apreciar que al hacer `console.log(nuevaCarta)` en la consola se muestra: "#document-fragment").

Estos fragmentos tienen una característica especial. Lo que se añade al DOM cuando se ejecuta `contenedorJugador1.appendChild(jugador1Carta)` no es el fragmento, sino el contenido del mismo. Pero el `addEventListener()` está añadiendo el event listener al fragmente y no a su contenido.

Para solucionar esto doy dos opciones:

#### Solución 1

Cambiar la etiqueta `<template>` por otra, tal como `div` o `section`. Esto ya queda a tu libre elección. Pero al hacer esto la propiedad [`template.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content) ya no estará disponible. Tendrías que cambiar también eso:

```
const nuevaCarta = template.children[0].cloneNode(true);
```

#### Solución 2

Cambiar la forma en la que obtienes el contenido del template:

```
const nuevaCarta =  template.content.children[0].cloneNode(true);
```

Así accedes al contenido del template (`template.content` que es el fragmento) y luego al contenido del fragmento (`content.children[0]` que es el article).

[image: Ejemplo solucionado screenshot]

Notar que en ambas soluciones es posible hacerlo con el código que he proporcionado porque `<template>` solo tiene un elemento hijo, en caso contrario `template.children[0]` solo tomaría el primer elemento dentro del template.

Comment: Recuerda que en [es.so] las respuestas aceptadas no representan una "solución", sino la respuesta que ha sido más útil para OP. En ese caso, pídele a OP que acepte la respuesta para que su pregunta no sea relanzada al inicio por el bot _Comunidad_, y pídeselo a lo sumo a través de un comentario, no en la respuesta misma, ya que representa ruido (así como las salutaciones y las firmas).

Comment: @padaleiana entendido